# SQLITE query to desire results

Tags: sqlite

I have the table in the format (CUSTOMER)     (FIG 1.1)

```
M_CODE  H_CODE END_TIME_OF_SERVICE ADULT ADULT_F
TKLK    LONE     09:19:16           1     2
TKLK    LONE     09:22:11           4     6
TKLK    LONE     09:32:46           2     7
TKLK    LONE     09:32:46           4     9
TKLK    LONE     10:09:36           1     3
```

and if i run the ( SELECT strftime('%H:%M', end, '-9 minutes') || ' - ' || strftime('%H:%M', end ) AS time_slot FROM end_times ) it gives the correct output as (FIG - 1.2)

```
09:19 - 09:28
09:29 - 09:38
09:39 - 09:48
09:49 - 09:58
09:59 - 10:08
10:09 - 10:18
```

Can you guide how to map these two tables, let`s say the the records in CUSTOMER table should be summed up for adult and adult_f column with( FIG 1.2 to FIG 1.1 )

```
   ADULT    ADULT_F    TIME_SLOT
      5        8      09:19 - 09:28
      6       16      09:29 - 09:38
      0        0      09:39 - 09:48
      0        0      09:49 - 09:58
      0        0      09:59 - 10:08
      1        3      10:09 - 10:18
```

Kindly guide me a solution, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to get the start/end times in a format that we can easily compare (we can combine them later):

```
SELECT strftime('%H:%M', end, '-9 minutes') AS slot_start,
       strftime('%H:%M', end              ) AS slot_end
FROM end_times
```

Then we can join this to the `CUSTOMER` table, while ignoring the seconds:

```
SELECT ADULT,
       ADULT_F,
       slot_start,
       slot_end
FROM (SELECT strftime('%H:%M', end, '-9 minutes') AS slot_start,
             strftime('%H:%M', end              ) AS slot_end
      FROM end_times)
     LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER
     ON substr(END_TIME_OF_SERVICE, 1, 5) BETWEEN slot_start AND slot_end
```

Finally, we group by the slot to get the sums per slot. I'm using [`total`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) instead of `sum` to get a zero for `NULL` values:

```
SELECT total(ADULT),
       total(ADULT_F),
       slot_start || ' - ' || slot_end
FROM (SELECT strftime('%H:%M', end, '-9 minutes') AS slot_start,
             strftime('%H:%M', end              ) AS slot_end
      FROM end_times)
     LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER
     ON substr(END_TIME_OF_SERVICE, 1, 5) BETWEEN slot_start AND slot_end
GROUP BY slot_start
```

Comment: Excellent CL , Again Thank you so much

Comment: Hi CL, Hope i am not disturbing you i tried my best to figure out the same with 30 minutes interval but could not get the desired results. Can you provide your help to generate the query with 30mins intervals pls..

Comment: Changing `end_times` and the `strftime` offset should work. If you have a question, ask the question *as a question*.

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for your time and kindly chk the newly created question as a asked. kindly do the needfull to generate for 30mins http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044512/sql-query-to-tune-it-better